# getting the result of sql command in java

Tags: java, sql

i need to get the last id entered in my data base witch is AUTO_INCREMENT so i did this

```
 String Var = "SELECT MAX(id) FROM goupe ; ";
     ResultSet vari=st.executeQuery(Var);
     while(vari.next()){
     nombre = vari.getInt("id");}
     String sql = "INSERT INTO Student(name,famillyname,email,password,module,speciality,card,id_goupe)VALUES('"+name+"','"+familly+"','"+email+"','"+pass+"','"+module+"','"+specialite+"','"+card+"','"+nombre+"');";
                st.execute(sql);
```

but i had this problem  Column 'id' not found.
so what should i do to have it right .

Comment: Give a name to your  result, e.g `SELECT MAX(id) AS maxid FROM goupe` ..`vari.getInt("maxid")`

Comment: Alternatively, you could do `vari.getInt(1)` to get the value of the first column of the result.

Comment: thank you @Berger it did work

Comment: thank you @SurfMan that did work too

Comment: ob [xkcd](https://www.xkcd.com/327/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to say, there are a couple of really easy things you can do to greatly improve your code.

- If your latest ID is generated elsewhere, then embed the query directly into the statement such that you don't need to go get it.  That will reduce the risk of  a race condition.
- Use PreparedStatements.  Let me ask you this question: What do you suppose is going to happen if one of your user's name is O'Ryan?

Since your code is just a snip, I also will only provide a snip:

```
int index = 1;
String sql = "INSERT INTO Student(name,famillyname,email,password,module,speciality,card,id_goupe)" + 
    "VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,(SELECT MAX(id) FROM goupe));";
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setString(index++, name);
ps.setString(index++, familyname);
ps.setString(index++, email);
ps.setString(index++, password);
ps.setString(index++, module);
ps.setString(index++, speciality);
ps.setString(index++, card);
int rows = ps.executeUpdate();
if(rows == 1) {
    System.out.println("Successfully inserted row");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you execute the query `SELECT MAX(id) FROM goupe;`, then in the returned table, the column name no longer remains as `id`.

So, the best approach is to provide a name for the column like below:

```
SELECT MAX(id) AS maxid FROM goupe;
```

Then, you can get the value using:

```
vari.getInt("maxid")
```